# How to use .distinct to remove objects from an array via the content of a object property

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I would like to understand the .distinct operator in my use-case:

I do a search for a country via user input and want to show only one object with a specific content in a property called country.

Explanation:

I have a BehaviorSubject with the content of various objects:

```
[
 {id:1, country: "United Kingdom", city:"London"},
 {id:2, country: "United Kingdom", city:"Manchester"},
 {id:3, country: "Germany", city:"Berlin"},
 ...
]
```

The type of the array is for example `loc[]`:

```
interface loc {
  id: number;
  country: string;
  city: string;
}
```

This is the filtering via user input (called 'query' in the code below):

```
BehaviorSubject
   .map(x => x.filter((l) => 
     l.country.toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase()) > -1))
```

If the user input is 'United' I get a result array with two objects.

To get only one object I used another `.map` to handle the duplicates (Standard js code to remove duplicates from an array) and return an array with only one object.

1. How do I remove the duplicates in the array with `.distinct`?
2. If you look at the first `.map` the type of `x` is `loc[]`. How do I get the items of the array in the `.map` operator and not the array type?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like with everything in rxjs: There are tons of ways, how to do this - this is how I would do it:

About the [`distinct`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-distinct): As described in the [docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-distinct), it takes an optional keySelector-function as the first parameter, where you can return the country:

```
.distinct(entry => entry.country)
```

Here is the full example:

```js
const allEntries$ = Rx.Observable.from([
 {id:1, country: "United Kingdom", city:"London"},
 {id:2, country: "United Kingdom", city:"Manchester"},
 {id:3, country: "Germany", city:"Berlin"}
])
  .publishReplay()
  .refCount();

const userInput$ = new Rx.ReplaySubject("");
// just for demonstration-purposes
userInput$.subscribe(input => console.log(">> Userinput: " + input));

// this is the important block
const result$ = userInput$
  .switchMap(input => allEntries$
    .filter(forCountry(input))
    .distinct(byCountry)
  );

// some helper for the filter, you could also do this inline, but it reads better this way
function forCountry(country) {
  country = country || "";
  coutnry = country.toLowerCase();
  return entry => entry.country.toLowerCase().indexOf(country) >= 0;
}

// some helper for the distinct, you could also do this inline, but it reads better this way
function byCountry(entry) {
  return entry.country;
}

// --- Simulation start
result$.subscribe(result => console.log(">>>> Result: " + result.city)); // activate the stream

userInput$.next("united");
userInput$.next("germ");
userInput$.next("e");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would you handle your example when you have an BehaviorSubject<ArrayofObjects> instead of the Observable.of<ArrayofObjects>?

Comment: That should make no difference - the only thing is, that the `distinct` might behave differently if that BehaviorSubject changes more often then the userInput - but that could be fixed with adding and additional level in the current switchMap.